# How to write a wrapper around fmt.Print

Tags: go

```
func myPrint(a...fmt.Stringer) {
    fmt.Print(a)
}

func main(){
    myPrint(1,"asd")
}
```

I get "int does not implement String method"

How to write a wrapper around `fmt.Print()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `myPrint` to:

```
func myPrint(a ...interface{}) {
    fmt.Print(a...)
}
```